# yarnの使い方を教えてください

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/index.html#installation

こちらの`spectre.css`というCSSフレームワークを使ってみたいのですが、yarn(素のnpmも)をほとんど使ったことがありません。

`$ yarn add spectre.css`を実行すると`node_modules`というディレクトリに`spectre.css`というディレクトリが作られファイル群がインストールされるところまでは確認できました。

このCSSを読み込んだ`index.html`という静的なページをまずは作ってみたいのですが、どうやって読み込んだらいいのかがわかりません。

`node_modules/spectre.css/dist/`にCSSが入っているようなので、

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/spectre.css/dist/spectre.css">`とやれば読み込めるとは思うのですが、このやり方で正しいのでしょうか。
実際にウェブサイトを公開していく時に、`node_modules`という文字がパスに含まれているのは違和感があります。
そういうものなのでしょうか。

参考までに`node_modules/spectre.css/dist/`の中身

- spectre-exp.css
- spectre-exp.min.css
- spectre-icons.css
- spectre-icons.min.css
- spectre.css
- spectre.min.css

Answer (score 1):

はじめまして。アプリケーションの規模には依るかと思われますが、開発ではWebpackやBrowserifyなどのモジュール・バンドラなどをお使いでしょうか？ そうでなければ、node_modulesというパスが含まれてしまっても問題ありません。

npmやbowerなどでインストールされたサードパーティ・モジュールは、一般的にはWebpack, Browserify, Rollupなどのモジュール・バンドラと呼ばれる、ソースコード内での外部ファイルの読み込みの依存性解決を補助するツールによって、読み込み先のパスを気にせず使うことができます
。そうでない場合には、相対パスを指定して読み込む形で問題ありません。